Failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction
In the const sx = await sendAndConfirmTransaction i am getting error
const {
        Connection,
        Keypair,
        SystemProgram,
        SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
        TransactionInstruction,
        sendAndConfirmTransaction,
        Transaction,
    } = require('@solana/web3.js');
    const {
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    } = require('@solana/spl-token');
    const borsh = require("borsh");
    const { Buffer } = require("buffer");
    
    function createKeypairFromFile(path) {
        return Keypair.fromSecretKey(
            Buffer.from(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(path, "utf-8")))
        );
    }
    
    class Assignable {
        constructor(properties) {
            Object.keys(properties).map((key) => {
                return (this[key] = properties[key]);
            });
        }
    }
    
    class CreateTokenArgs extends Assignable {
        toBuffer() {
            return Buffer.from(borsh.serialize(CreateTokenArgsSchema, this));
        }
    }
    const CreateTokenArgsSchema = new Map([
        [
            CreateTokenArgs, {
                kind: 'struct',
                fields: [
                    ['token_decimals', 'u8'],
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]);
    
    describe("Create Tokens!",  () => {
    
        const connection = new Connection(`https://api.devnet.solana.com/`, 'confirmed');
        const payer = createKeypairFromFile(require('os').homedir() + '/.config/solana/id.json');
        const program = createKeypairFromFile('./ico/target/deploy/ico-keypair.json');
    
        it("Mint token!",  async () => {
    
            const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    
            const instructionData = new CreateTokenArgs({
                token_decimals: 9,
            });
    
            let ix = new TransactionInstruction({
                keys: [
                    { pubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },           
                    { pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },                
                    { pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true }, 
                    { pubkey: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },                 
                    { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },        
                    { pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },               
                ],
                programId: program.publicKey,
                data: instructionData.toBuffer(),
            });
    
            const ts = new Transaction().add(ix);
    
            const sx = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
                connection,
                ts,
                [payer, mintKeypair]
            );
    
            console.log("Success!");
            console.log(`Mint Address: ${mintKeypair.publicKey}`);
            console.log(ix);
            console.log(ts);
            console.log(sx);
        });
    
    });


What is the program address deployed at the devnet? Is it the same as the pubkey referred by keypair ./ico/target/deploy/ico-keypair.json?
